# What is the difference between structure and morphology in polymer blends?

Tags: molecular-structure, polymers, terminology, crystal-structure

When talking about polymer blends there is a difference between its structure and morphology, but I am not sure what it is. These two terms are used interchangeably in materials I use to study, but I don't see what is the difference if any.

Quote from my materials: "Properties of polymer blends are determined by component interactions and blend morphology." The next sentence: "Blend structure is determined by miscibillity of components."

Comment: You better elaborate more about that...

Comment: Morphology and structure can be very ambiguous terms, meaning just about anything (shape, tacticity, molecular conformation, macromolecular or crystal arrangement). It would be nice to see a good ("canonical") answer from somebody knowledgeable.

Comment: You might want to check the [IUPAC Compendium of Polymer Terminology and Nomenclature](https://iupac.org/cms/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Compendium-of-Polymer-Terminology-and-Nomenclature-IUPAC-Recommendations-2008.pdf).

Comment: They appear to be used as synonyms in this context. It is a reference to the structure-function paradigm in the context of polymer blends, where chain structure has a role to play in determining miscibility and therefore phase structure.

Answer (score 3):

In short:  it may be used as a question of scale.

- A polymer blend is a physical mixture of two (or more than two) polymers.  As such, you may compare it with granite, mainly consisting of grains of feldspar, quartz, and mica put together; here, different chemical compounds are present in one material and they retain their individual local chemistry.
- This contrasts to a copolymer (e.g., polyesters, polyamides) like PET, or nylon; here, the constituents are chemically bound together and form a new compound.
- Even for the (carbon based) polymers said to be crystalline, or to contain small local volumes with *some* regular, crystalline order, it is rare for polymers to have a unit cell-like local pattern which repeats itself in a predictable fashion multiple thousand times in the three directions of space by simple translation as observed, e.g., for $\ce{NaCl}$.

Thus *structure* (in the narrow sense) may be used to describe the spatial arrangement of polymer's atoms at a small scale (say a up to few $\pu{10 Å}$).  On the other hand, in comparison of the former, *morphology* is about shape/form/organization at larger scale of length (even if still microscopic) as e.g., for [spherulites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherulite_(polymer_physics)), [domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain), [grains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystallite) including properties observable if many molecules are in one place e.g., to yield a rough (*vs.* a smooth) surface.

Comment: Yes, this may be true. It is a question of scale.